# Max and Min records from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. The first table has columns `fileID`, `createdate`.  The second table has `userid`, `fileID`, `createdate` as common fields along with other columns.

I am trying to write a query to find latest `fileid(max)` and the first loaded `fileid(min)` based on the `createdate` for a specific userid by joining both these tables and using group by on fileid, createdate in the query and filtering the user id in the where clause.

However the result is showing all the rows.

I need a suggestion as how to write a query to get two records(max and min fileid records) only from both these tables and not all the records with these field changes.

I am using SQL Server to write the query.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to tag SQL Server, and also to provide the code that you have so far. This guide will help you provide a [mcve] so that people can help.

Comment: If you could add a query to your question it would make it easier to understand the question and wirte an naswer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select `fieldid` by earliest or latest `createdate` and to have it in two separate rows you can try something like this:

```
SELECT fileid, "earliest" as type
FROM table1
WHERE createdate = (SELECT MIN(createdate) from table1)
LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT fileid, "lattest" as type
FROM table1
WHERE createdate = (SELECT MAX(createdate) from table1)
LIMIT 1
```

It is not clear, why you want to join it with the second table, but you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM
  (
    SELECT fileid, "earliest" as type FROM table1 WHERE createdate = (SELECT 
    MIN(createdate) from table1) LIMIT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT fileid, "lattest" as type FROM table1 WHERE createdate = (SELECT 
    MAX(createdate) from table1) LIMIT 1
  ) as subquery1
LEFT JOIN
  table2 on table2.fileid = createdate.fileid
```